# Jquery code working on windows but not on Mac or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari

The following function remove the selected option from all the other select menus , it works well on windows chrome and firefox but not on Safari or Mac .

Do you have any idea of what could cause the problem please ?

HTML code :

```
<select>
    <option>slelect</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>slelect</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>slelect</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
     <option>slelect</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code :

```
(function () {
    var previous;
    $("select").on('focus', function () {
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function(){
        $elm = $(this).children('option:selected');
        $a = $elm.val();
        $('option[value=' + $a + ']').not($elm).hide();
        $('option[value=' + previous + ']').not($elm).show();   
    });
})();
```

Comment: Audi remains an option for me, even if I select it, it isn't removed from other selects. Using Windows 8 Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because .hide() simply adds a display:none css property to the option
The the problem lies within these lines:

```
  $('option[value=' + $a + ']').not($elm).hide();
  $('option[value=' + previous + ']').not($elm).show();
```

if we change those to use the disabled state, it works as expected

```
  $('option[value=' + $a + ']').not($elm).attr('disabled', 'disabled');;
  $('option[value=' + previous + ']').removeAttr("disabled");
```

What you are seeing is a browser discrepancy in the way select lists are allowed to be styled. Some browsers allow you to do things like change the background color. Some don't, which is why this is a bad approach. Just use the disabled state instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/o9qgmut8/

Comment: `.hide()` does not _"simply add a css class"_.  See:  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: @Sparky "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" )" this depends on the framework, I've been working in angular which actually does do the described behavior, but applying display none in css is equivalent, my answer is still correct, certain browsers don't allow you to style select options, but rather only the parent select element

Comment: However, calling `.css( "display", "none" )` is also **not** _"adding a class"_!  It's simply adding a CSS "style property".  Let's be correct with usage of terminology.

Comment: I can understand where you're coming from, but that's not really the issue at hand, I've updated the answer to reflect your change.

Comment: If it was the issue I would have posted my own answer and down-voted yours.  The issue is that I made a constructive suggestion about how you could make your answer better.  If you notice how things work around here... everything counts towards voting up/down... spelling, grammar, content, and proper usage of technical terminology.